# flutter определение локализации

Tags: flutter, dart

В телефоне в настройках установлено два языка: **английский** и *русский*. В ***данный момент*** выбран язык ***русский***.

1) определение локали в Kotlin -> ***ru_Ru*** -> правильно

```
textView.text = resources.configuration.locale.toString()
```

2) определение локали во Flutter -> ***en_EN*** -> не правильно

```
Localizations.localeOf(context).toString()
```

3) определение локали во Flutter -> ***ru_Ru*** -> правильно

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
ui.window.locale.toString()
```

Почему 2 вариант не правильно показывает локаль? Спасибо.

**полный код**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Text(
      '${Localizations.localeOf(context).toString()}\n${ui.window.locale.toString()}',
      style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.pink,
       fontSize: 36.0,
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: просто предположение, а если попробовать метод у класса Localizations:


static MaterialLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
   return Localizations.of<MaterialLocalizations>(context, MaterialLocalizations);
}
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Defines the Locale for its child and the localized resources that the child depends on.

Потому что вариант 2 используется для предоставление локализации виджетам ниже этого виджета в дереве (child). То есть нужна для создания перевода в приложении. Делаеться это посредством `Localizations` и `Localizations.override` (используются для ситуаций, когда часть приложения должна быть локализованной для другого языка), а по умолчанию в `locale` стоит `en_US`.

*[Источник](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Localizations-class.html)*